# SQL - return multiple values in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Using SSMS, Table that looks like this

| Agent | Location |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |

---

How I run a query to get:

| Agent | Location |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2 |
| B | 3,4 |

Comment: You need to tag the DBMS, and probably the specific version too. For example, answers for MS SQL Server 2019 will be different for MS SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Hi Zack, if you want to return only distinct location, what is your expected result based on the table above with extra row: ```Agent - C, Location - 1```. 
Is it going to be another row in the result table with ```Agent - C, Location - 1```, or should it be omitted as you want only distinct locations (because it is already returned by the first row, ```Agent - A, Location - 1,2```)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) You want this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42778050/14868997

Answer (score 1):

You could try a Self Join on the Agent field like this:

```
SELECT 
  AGENT_A as AGENT, 
  CONCAT(CONCAT(LOCATION_A, ','), LOCATION_B) as LOCATION 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    A.AGENT as AGENT_A, 
    A.LOCATION as LOCATION_A, 
    B.AGENT as AGENT_B, 
    B.LOCATION as LOCATION_B 
  FROM SSMS as A
    LEFT JOIN SSMS as B
      on A.Agent = B.Agent) as T
WHERE LOCATION_A < LOCATION_B
```

Here you can see a Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00cb9ecb7f0584c2436a0ee6bca6a30b

Comment: Nice, but [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can also receive more then 2 parameters, so nesting it is not needed...  (and I do think the real problem might have more than 2 values which need to be comma-separated...)

Answer (score 0):

I use SQL Server 2019, but it also works for Azure sql db. So, if you want to return only distinct values, I'd suggest using rank() over() to discard any duplicated values from other agents. There is only one drawback, first unique location would be received by the first available agent.

In the code it is more clear to understand:

```
Create table Agents
(
    Agent char(1),
    Location int
)

insert into Agents
VALUES
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('A', 6),
('B', 3),
('B', 4),
('C', 1),
('C', 4),
('C', 5)

select Agent, STRING_AGG([Location], ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Location ASC) as Locations
from
(   
    select Agent, Location, rank() over (partition by [Location] order by Agent) as rnk
    from Agents
) as t
--will return agents with distinct locations, because they have the rank equals to 1
where t.rnk = 1
group by Agent
```

Here is link to test it: [SQLize Online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/54fd8c8f78a9cb04e42ad249603cd2a9/)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte1 as (
  SELECT 
     Agent, 
     CAST(Location AS VARCHAR(MAX)) Location,
     row_number() over (partition by Agent order by Location) R
  FROM SSMS
  ),
ctec as (
   SELECT Agent, count(*)  as c
   FROM SSMS
   GROUP BY Agent),
cte2 (Agent, Location, i, L) as (
   SELECT 
      Agent,
      CONCAT(Location,'') Location,
      1 as i ,
      Location L
   from cte1 
   where R=1
   
   union all
   
   select 
       cte2.Agent,
       CONCAT(cte2.Location, ',', cte1.Location),
       i+1,
       cte1.Location

   from cte1
   inner join cte2 on cte2.Agent=cte1.Agent 
                  and cte1.Location > cte2.Location  and cte1.R = i+1
   inner join ctec on cte2.Agent= ctec.Agent
   where  i < ctec.c
)

SELECT Agent,Location 
FROM cte2
WHERE i=(select c from ctec where ctec.Agent=cte2.Agent)
ORDER BY Agent;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7c03fa58785fc2db647c188d739aca6e)

output, with some added data:

```
INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('C', '5');
INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('C', '6');
INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('C', '7');

INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('D', '5');
INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('D', '3');
INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('D', '1');
INSERT INTO SSMS VALUES ('D', '2');
```

| Agent | Location |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2 |
| B | 3,4 |
| C | 5,6,7 |
| D | 1,2,3,5 |